# Getting Logos from Sites with SiteInfo

Tags: soap, yodlee

We are attempting to get site logos from the Yodlee API. From the `SiteInfo` data model (using the SOAP API), there are the following methods that appear to retrieve site logos

```
siteInfo.getDefaultSiteLogo()
siteInfo.getLocalizedSiteLogos()
getDefaultFavIcon()
```

The issue is that these methods for the sites we are using (all sites with the AU geography) are returning `null`.

I am pretty sure this is possible to do, since Yodlee's own fastlink does show logos for sites as you are adding them.

**Here are the method call signatures**

I am using the soap api through java (using axis 1.4, just like in the sample code) and the API signatures are as follows

`SiteAccountManagementService` has the method `getAllSiteAccounts` which has the following signature

`com.yodlee.soap.collections.core.accountmanagement.ArrayOfSiteAccountInfo getAllSiteAccounts(com.yodlee.soap.common.UserContext userContext)`.

Then there is also getCctx, which has the following signature
`public com.yodlee.soap.common.CobrandContext getCctx()`

None of these methods have a `request specifier` parameter of any sought

Answer (score 0):

I don't think icons will be returned by default. I believe you need to specify this in your request specifier to get icons/image.

Comment: Is there any documentation for this, I can't seem to find where you need to do this (in any of the yodlee docs, the operations that return site info, such as searchSite or getAllContentServices, take no parameters, or in the case of searchSite, just the query string)

Comment: I don't have doc with me. But can you please post your API signature. I'm sure there are API which takes "requestSpecifier" as one of the parameter.

Comment: No. `SiteAccountManagementService` is not the right one. You should be checking only in searchSite or contentService accordingly. For example [link](http://developer.yodlee.com/Indy_FinApp/Aggregation_Services_Guide/Aggregation_SOAP_API_Reference/getAllContentServices)

Comment: Try to set all the bits in reqSpecifier to 1

Answer (score 0):

[getAllSiteAccounts](http://developer.yodlee.com/Indy_FinApp/Aggregation_Services_Guide/Aggregation_REST_API_Reference/getAllSiteAccounts) API is to get the details for the Accounts aggregated by a consumer,
while the information you are looking for(the Logos) are site related not consumer related.
You should use [getSiteInfo](http://developer.yodlee.com/Indy_FinApp/Aggregation_Services_Guide/Aggregation_REST_API_Reference/getSiteInfo)(under SiteTraversal) to get this specific detail and remember to pass value of `siteFilter.reqSpecifier` as 128.